# How to add a field for filename, that populates the filename for each row of data extracted from the parsed pdfs?

Tags: python, parsing, append

I am parsing files from a directory and compiling the data into a csv. I want to add the filename of each file parsed to my output by creating a column called "Label". Below is my current code that works. I just need to add filename (Label). I would appreciate any help.

```
import sys
import os
from pyresparser import ResumeParser
output = 'EMAIL,SKILLS,'
for filename in os.listdir('/Users/NSam/Documents/resume/directory'):
    output += '\n'
    d = ResumeParser('/Users/NSam/Documents/resume/directory/' + filename).get_extracted_data()
    for key, value in d.items():
        if str(key) == 'email':
            output += str(value) + ','
        if str(key) == 'skills':    
            for skillkey in value:
                output += str(skillkey) + ','
sys.stdout.write(output)
with open('/Users/NSam/Documents/resume/directory/output.csv', 'w') as f:
    print('', output, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code above is missing the part where you write to the csv file. I normally like to write to csv files using the `DictWriter` in the standard library `csv`. Below is a code snip-it of how it works.

Test it out and see if it works for your code.

```
from csv import DictWriter
from os import listdir

with open('file.csv', 'w') as write_file:
    for fl in listdir():
        dict_writer = DictWriter(write_file,
                                 ['file_name', 'test1', 'test2']
                                 )
        dict_values = {'file_name':fl, 'test1':'Hello2', 'test2':"Hello3"}
        dict_writer.writerow(dict_values)
```

**EDIT**
Based on the comment below I added the `for fl in listdir('path/to/file')` this will list all the files and directories in the `path/to/file` and put them as the first column in the csv.

**EDIT2** So the below is just copy and pasting your code and adding what I think will make it add the filename.It looks like the way you are using `output` that you could just add the `filename` to the `output` right after you add the newline. Test this out and see if it works for you.  **I would like to say that this is not the perferred way to write to a csv file in python. The easiest way would be to use the csv package as mentioned above**

```
import sys

import os
from pyresparser import ResumeParser
output = 'EMAIL,SKILLS,'
for filename in os.listdir('/Users/NSam/Documents/resume/directory'):
    output += '\n'
    output += filename + ','
    d = ResumeParser('/Users/NSam/Documents/resume/directory/' + filename).get_extracted_data()
    for key, value in d.items():
        if str(key) == 'email':
            output += str(value) + ','
        if str(key) == 'skills':    
            for skillkey in value:
                output += str(skillkey) + ','
sys.stdout.write(output)
with open('/Users/NSam/Documents/resume/directory/output.csv', 'w') as f:
    print('', output, file=f)
```

Comment: thanks but this did not work. I'm new to python so I may be missing something... I also do not see where you are calling out the names of each file in the directory and writing it into the corresponding rows...

Comment: thanks but this still did not work. when I tried it, it adds the filenames to the bottom of my data instead of adding a new column in for filename beside the data... Again, I'm just missing something. Can you show me where this should fit into my code? I already have a file that I'm writing my output to in the last two lines.